# Copy data from one matrix to another

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, copy

In C++, I am trying to copy data from one matrix to another. My code is as follows:

```
int data[height][width];
void MyCode::setData ( int newData[height][width] )
{   
    for ( int i = 0; i < height; i ++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < width; j ++ )
        {
            data[i][j] = newData[i][j];
        }   
    }       
}
```

My problem here is, these "for" loops are too time consuming, and the code stops just here (maybe the memory is overloaded, I am reading video frames). I wondered about using pointers, like this:

```
int* data[height][width];
void MyCode::setData ( int* newData[height][width] )
{   
     data = newData;
}
```

But it didn't work, I don't know the reason. Could someone suggest me a better solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure that this is `for` loop who works long? Are your arrays of extreme size?

Comment: My arrays are of size 600x800 that come from video frames, so I think the size is not the point causing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way round this is to use a 1D array that is width * height in size.  This way you can easily memcpy the data between the two.

Its easy to work out from a row and column what the eventual position in the 1D array is by doing the following:

```
int index = column + (row * width);
```

Edit: If you must use a 2D array then one of the dimensions MUST be known.

As such you can do the following:

```
int data[height][width];
void MyCode::setData ( int (*newData)[width] )
{   
    for ( int i = 0; i < height; i ++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < width; j ++ )
        {
            data[i][j] = newData[i][j];
        }   
    }       
}
```

In C++ you really are better off using something like a template based solution or such like though as if you pass in an array with the wrong height dimension you will get problems and the compiler will not catch it.

There are plenty of template matrix libraries around. For example:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tmv-cpp/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I cannot reshape the matrix into 1D, because I am using it in some other classes as 2D.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Boost's multidimensional array. It's possible that it implements a more efficient copy operation:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Additionally, I'd take a look at Blitz++. This lib uses template meta-programming in c++ to eliminate temporaries and they might have well optimized such matrix operations. This is what their project states:

> Blitz++ is a C++ class library for scientific computing which provides performance on par with Fortran 77/90. It uses template techniques to achieve high performance. Blitz++ provides dense arrays and vectors, random number generators, and small vectors (useful for representing multicomponent or vector fields).

http://blitz.sourceforge.net/

Hope that helps!